# Getting an error (PLS-00201) when trying to use REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I am new at PL SQL and ran into a problem when trying to use REGEXP_SUBSTR in a SQL Procedure.  I have a String when is a single line from a file and I am trying to isolate one element of that line lik so

```
 "batch_number := REGEXP_SUBSTR(lv_f_line, '[^,]+', 1, 1);"
```

The error I get is:

```
 "Error(124,25): PLS-00201: identifier 'REGEXP_SUBSTR' must be declared"
```

Now I undserstand that this is a common error but why on REGEXP_SUBSTR which is not an identifier?  I have looked around for an answer and I just cannot find anything.  Can anyone shed some light please?

Many thanks, K.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using. Regular expressions were introduced in Oracle 10.2, maybe you're trying to create this procedure on an earlier version of the database where the REGEXP functions don't exist.

Comment: @Shankar, regular expressions were introduced 10.1 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/wnsql.htm#sthref11

Answer (score 0):

REGEXP_SUBSTR is an SQL function. It may not be available in PL/SQL.

Try something like

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(lv_f_line, '[^,]+', 1, 1)
into batch_number
from dual;
```

That's not too efficiecnt because of context switching but may work if you don't execute it many times